# How do I get a column instead of rows as a result in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

MY table is similar the one below. My goal is to get the total points of each person ( WHERE username = 'Bobby' OR username= 'George') and return the result in columns instead of rows. (Note: I have more than two username in my table and each of them contain specific points, in this case I am trying to retrieve the specific total points based on two people specified).

```
id   |   username   |   points
1        Bobby            1
2        George           3
3        Bobby            2
4        Bobby            2
5        George           1
```

Desire Results:

```
column_1(Bobby)  |  column_2 (George)
       5                  4
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Here's a tutorial how to transpose your table. http://oracletuts.net/sql/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of getting it as a result of sql, you could get your rows first and bind to some datagridview, then have another datagridview where u add the rows as column, and have the first datagridview hidden in the form...I am guessing you are trying to display a form...I am sorry if I wasn't any help..

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot table for above problem.

Try:

```
select sum(case when name = "Bobby" then point end) as Bobby,
    sum(case when name = "George" then point end) as George from tablename;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dad5c/9